# Security difference between textarea and input HTML elements?

Tags: node.js, html, security, https, frontend

I'm new to HTML frontend and general coding. I am wondering if there's any security differences between the input and textarea elements.

From what i understand so far:

1. The input element can assign a 1 line input string to it's value
   attribute.
2. The textarea element can assign multiple lines of
   text to it's value attribute and has an adjustable input field size.

I can see the clear advantage of using a textarea over an input field for most cases, but are there any security issues I should test for in building a serverless web application and how should I?

For instance: I know I should test and validate the input strings and escape any bad characters. Is there a best practice way of doing this? Do i have to validate on the server side or can i validate as an event in the background js? What other security vulnerabilities should i expect.

The input data is being used to construct a triple nested JSON of user input meta-data to be used in instantiating a deep learning example program. (i.e. it takes an essay as input, processes it into phrases, sentences, and paragraphs, and sorts them into a json-tree.)

Comment: Correction: A plain textarea doesn't support "rich text" in any way.

Comment: Beyond that, your server can never trust any data sent to it from the client anyway, and the client is only going to send strings, regardless of whether they were input in an input element or textarea or just with a spoofed HTTP request, so there's no difference there at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

There are no security differences between any HTML elements.

All security-related checks are done at server and security level depends on those validation checks only. 
Best practices used depend on your back-end language / framework.

Comment: Small note there: You have the `password` field type, which will hide the exact input, and depending on the browser, you might not be allowed to copy content out of it.

That being said, the server needs to handle all the security regarding form submission and such. Any client input should not be trusted.